# change behavior of python unhandled Exception to send emails

Tags: python, email, exception, subclass

I want to change the behavior of unhandled Exceptions (all of them) in python to send emails without changing code very much or using special error handlers everywhere.

My hope is to subclass Exception and then redefine it at the beginning of a given module.

So the subclassing is here:

```
class ExceptionMailer(Exception):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.message = m
        send_email(email_address,self.message)
```

Then at the at the begining of a module I can do this:

```
Exception = ExceptionMailer
```

Then when an Exception is raised an email with it's message is sent. I have gotten this to work strictly for `Exception`  but not for say `ValueError`. My hope was that redefining `Exception` would redefine all the error types but I was clearly wrong. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: Setting a a built-in classes `__bases__` attribute does not seem to be possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In the moment you redefine `Exception`, all its subclasses were created, so it doesn't affect them:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def a(self):
        print 'a in A'

>>> class B(A):
    pass

>>> B().a()
a in A
>>> class C(object):
    def a(self):
        print 'a in C'

>>> A = C
>>> B().a()
a in A
```

Regarding your problem.  Take a look at [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).  It allows you to redefine program behavior in case of any uncaught exception.

Comment: Can you please explain why you think this is the right way to do this? Also, I'm not 100% sure how to do this right this second ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the behavior of Exceptions (all of them) ...

No, you don't. In Python, exceptions are used for flow control. For example, your handler would fire every time a `StopIteration` is raised, or a comparison function fails, or a library uses an exception to signal something.

Instead, simply wrap your code in

```
try:
   # ... large block of code
except BaseException as e:
   send_email(email_address, e.message)
```

Comment: Are you saying I should try to wrap *all* of my code in one big try except? Is this good practice?

Comment: That is best practice. You don't need to actually indent much code, just wrap the call to your `main` method or other similar root methods.